# Conditional Field on Multiple Selects Module

Tags: forms

I have 1 Multiple Select field and 2 Select List fields:

[image]

I need to show those 2 Select field only when Multiple Select has a value of 1 (the first value of the list is selected). I made the dependency and the 2 Select lists are hidden, but when I select the first value of the Multiple Select field, the 2 fields are not appearing, nothing happens.

[image]

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Any opinions why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work when I use these settings. See screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you check if it will work when you change Number of Values to Unlimited ? Thanks

Comment: Not sure which field you want me to set that but it also works when I set all fields (choose an item, fabric, suit_category) to Number of Values to Unlimited